# How to use meta character in SQLite query

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to do searching some pattern in the database from my application.
But my DB query is not working.Gives Syntax error near "%": while compiling: SELECT _id,note From Notes Where note=%?

```
public Cursor getAll(String id) {
        String[] args = { id };
        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
                "SELECT _id,city From City Where city=%?%", args));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public Cursor getAll(String id) {
        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
                "SELECT _id,city From City Where city like '%" + id + "%'", null));
    }
```